# Por qué 25200056 / 20971520 es igual a 1 en Java?

Tags: java

Por qué

```
System.out.println(25200056 / 20971520);
```

Imprime 1 y no 1.201632308959961?

Comment: La división de 2 enteros da 1 entero

Comment: si declaro una variable double o float sigue marcando 1.

Comment: Comparte el código, ahí veo que muestras la división de 2 enteros, dale en [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/496895/edit) para modificar tu pregunta.

Comment: Ya vi, lo que pasa es que ese valor me lo pasaron directo y no sabía por qué es que salia eso aunque lo guardara en una variable double. Guardo los valores en sus tipos primero y luego hago la operacón. Gracias

Comment: Si quieres mostrar la división con decimales era suficiente con que uno de ellos sea decimal: ``System.out.println(25200056.0 / 20971520);``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aquí la solución:

```
        float a = 25200056;
        float e = 20971520;
        double n = a / e;
        System.out.println(n); //imprime 1.2016322612762451
```

Primero almaceno la información en una variable float y luego hago la operación.

Comment: también aplica si no quieres hacer todo eso:
System.out.println(25200056.0 / 20971520.0); al añadir el .0 considera el número float